# Cross update data on two columns in same worksheet for specific item google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, I want to 'cross-talk' between column **C** and **K** for each specific items (links in this case) situated in column **D** (*containing various links from web starting from* = ***D5***).

The whole worksheet is devided in two section (See the image):

1. **Main Database** [1. Worksheet Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGFvV.jpg)
2. **Filtered Data** (Fitering the *links* in **D5:D** )
   [2.'Filter' formulas I've used - Take a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9xOG.jpg)

if I select ***"Done"*** for the item in **C5**  (3.Immunology → 1.Transgenic Animals → 2.Biotechnology and Applied Zoology), I want to select ***"Done"*** in **K16**. ***And vice versa***. I want this to happen for all items.
See pictures : [3. C5→K16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYwfk.jpg) & [4. K16→C5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83AN2.jpg)

Also I'm using Google Apps Script for *Multirow dependent dropdown list* -

```
//Sheet = 'Link Database' - Creating suitable dependant Dropdown 
function onEdit(){
  //this line refers to the current active sheet
  var start = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  //this 'current' variable captures the currently selected cell in the active spreadsheet
  var current = start.getActiveCell();

  //var to refer to the worksheet
  var topicDatabase = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Topic Database");
  var linkDatabase = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Link Database");
  //has the user selected a subject?
  if (current.getColumn()==5)
  {
    //to copy the selcted subject
    var coiceSubject = current.getValue()
    topicDatabase.getRange("P2").setValue(coiceSubject)

    //clear any validation
    linkDatabase.getRange("F5:F").clearDataValidations();

    //create the rule
    var point = current.offset(0,1)
    var items = topicDatabase.getRange("N2:N")
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(items).build();
    
    //clear content
    point.clearContent();
    point.setDataValidation(rule)

  }
  //has the user selected a topic?
  if(current.getColumn()==6)
  {
    //to copy the selected topic
    var choiceTopic = current.getValue()
    topicDatabase.getRange("Q2").setValue(choiceTopic)
    

    //clear any validation
    linkDatabase.getRange("G5:G").clearDataValidations();


    //create the rule
    var point2 = current.offset(0,1)
    var items2 = topicDatabase.getRange("O2:O")
    var rule2 = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(items2).build();

    point2.clearContent();
    point2.setDataValidation(rule2)
  }
  //if subject is blank - clear content & validation in topic and sub topic
  if(linkDatabase.getRange("E5:E").isBlank()==true){
    //clear validaton on the same range
    linkDatabase.getRange("F5:F").clearDataValidations();
    linkDatabase.getRange("G5:G").clearDataValidations();

    linkDatabase.getRange("F5:F").clearContent()
    linkDatabase.getRange("G5:G").clearContent()
 }
  else if(linkDatabase.getRange("F5:F").isBlank()==true){
    linkDatabase.getRange("G5:G").clearDataValidations();
    linkDatabase.getRange("G5:G").clearContent()
  }
}
```

**Link of the google sheet [Updated with solved answer]** : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-Oz4F02UnHrf9x_tBZLNU2BK5aMUHdfFgKnhjANMeTI/copy

Comment: Your filter is not fix. What is the expected behavior if you marked C5 as done then you change the filter criteria to a different video? Are you open for an apps script solution? if yes please also provide a sample sheet

Comment: @RonM
I'm open for apps script solution! 
Here is a link for the sheet : 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-Oz4F02UnHrf9x_tBZLNU2BK5aMUHdfFgKnhjANMeTI/copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can refer to this sample code:

```
//Sheet = Link Database - Creating suitable dependant Dropdown 
function onEdit(e){

  // YOUR ORIGINAL CODE HERE..... //
 
  if(start.getName() == "Link Database" ){


    //Get list of filtered links in B5:B
    var filteredLinks = linkDatabase.getRange("B5:B").getDisplayValues().flat().filter(String);
    //Get all links in D5:D
    var allLinks = linkDatabase.getRange("D5:D").getDisplayValues().flat().filter(String);
    Logger.log(filteredLinks)
    Logger.log(allLinks)

    //Check if filter criteria was updated, update column C based on column K value
    if(current.getColumn()==2 && current.getRow() >= 2 && current.getRow() <= 4){
      //Clear content of C5:C
      linkDatabase.getRange("C5:C").clearContent();

      //Update status of each filtered links
      filteredLinks.forEach((link,index) => {
        var idx = allLinks.indexOf(link);

        if(idx > -1){
          //Get status value in column K
          var status = linkDatabase.getRange(5+idx,11).getDisplayValue();
          //Set status value in column C
          linkDatabase.getRange(5+index,3).setValue(status);
        }
      });
    }

    //Get the rows being updated using the event object 'e'
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
    var rowStart = e.range.rowStart;
    var rowCnt = e.range.rowEnd - rowStart;
    
    //Loop each row
    for(var i = 0; i <= rowCnt; i++){
      var currentRow = rowStart + i;
      Logger.log(currentRow);
      //Check if status in column C5:C was updated. Update status in column K
      if(current.getColumn()==3 && currentRow >= 5){
        var status = linkDatabase.getRange(currentRow,current.getColumn()).getDisplayValue();

        Logger.log(status);
        //Get matching filtered link
        var index = currentRow - 5;
        //Get the filtered link index in allLink array
        var idx = allLinks.indexOf(filteredLinks[index]);
        Logger.log(idx);
        if(idx > -1){
          //link found. Set status in column K
          linkDatabase.getRange(5+idx,11).setValue(status);
        }else{
          //revert modification
          current.clearContent();
        }
      }

      //Check if status in column K5:K was updated. Update status in column C
      if(current.getColumn()==11 && currentRow >= 5){
        var status = linkDatabase.getRange(currentRow,current.getColumn()).getDisplayValue();
        Logger.log(status);
        //Get matching link
        var idx = currentRow - 5;
        //Get the filtered link index in allLink array
        var index = filteredLinks.indexOf(allLinks[idx]);
        Logger.log(index);
        if(index > -1){
          //link found. Set status in column K
          linkDatabase.getRange(5+index,3).setValue(status);
        }
      }

    }
    
  }

}
```

### Modifications added:

1. Handle updating of status in column `C5:C` when the filter criteria in `B2, B3, B4` were changed.
2. Handle updating of status in column `K5:K` when the status in column `C5:C` were changed.
3. Handle updating of status in column `C5:C` when the status in column `K5:K` were changed.

### Note:

To get the number of rows being modified, I used the [onEdit event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) `e`. Then loop each rows one-by-one to update the status for column C or K.

Please be mindful that if you run the script manually using the editor, you will encounter an error object `e` is undefined. It is because the event object only exist when you modify/edit a cell in your sheet. To debug the code I need to edit a cell/range of cells in the sheet then check the logs under execution tab.

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered some issues so i could update accordingly

Comment: Thank you so much @RonM. The code is working as expected! 
However,I think there's a limitation if there are 100 items we have to select 'Done' one by one. Bulk editing on C5:C is no applicable and same goes for K5:K, is there any solution for this?

Comment: You mean you tried to copy paste 'Done' in column C5:C? how about in K5:K is bulk status update should also be available?

Comment: Please let me give you a .gif link about this. It is rendering now! 
I dragged the 'Done' from C5 to say C10 it is just updating one/two values

Comment: Noted. I'll wait for the link before i  update the answer

Comment: Link to youtube - https://youtu.be/jD9gmkKMGoc
for bulk editing issue

Comment: I updated the answer, please check if it works from your side. You can remove unnecessary logs afterwards. I just used them to debug the code.

Comment: The issue is fixed! Check out the video! 
https://youtu.be/8ineumVVCIw

Comment: Glad to hear that